# get transactions/logs from different program, on a span of blocks

Tags: rust, program, logs

Here is the situation:

I'm using Rust.
I need to be able to "listen" to transaction, or at least logs from a list of solana program. I cannot use Websocket's "logsubscribe" function, as I would need multiple sockets for each program, and in case of disconnection, if I restart, I will have no way of getting the logs I missed.
I do not need full history, only logs on recent blocks.
If I cannot get the logs from block x to block y, getting logs of block x, x+1... y is also viable for me.

I couldn't find any good solution but to fetch a whole block, iterate over every transaction, get the program id, compare to my "list" of program, and if it matches, iterate over the logs until I find what I want. But that's actually a lot of iteration, and I couldn't figure out how to get the program id (as the the `program_id` method is only available on Legacy `Message`, and I get `VersionedMessage` from the logs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're doing the right thing for your situation -- fetching the whole block and iterating through it is perfectly valid.

Your other question seems to be about actually iterating through the transactions in the block. You can get the program ids in the transaction from the logs themselves.

Check out this transaction: https://explorer.solana.com/tx/64R6ue3hqZUs5STk8LLBcTr7A4BaE9hL51KHY6gwWUeYXiVHgT8s8zchxm98D4aKSDnQZAPDqzojyiCpZaud4kGP

If you look at the raw logs at the bottom, you'll see lines like:

```
Program 675kPX9MHTjS2zt1qfr1NYHuzeLXfQM9H24wFSUt1Mp8 invoke [1]
```

So you can search on that in the logs to see whenever a program is called.

Comment: But how optimized is this solution ? I just deployed a contract, and it displayed "275 transactions", if each interaction with Solana makes this much txs, don't I risk having my program being slower than the block productions ?

Comment: Using `logsSubscribe` is the most optimized solution, but if you don't want to use it, `getBlock` is your next best option. It's certainly possible for your listening solution to fall behind, so be sure that it has enough bandwidth and processing power!

Comment: I see. Thanks for your answer then, maybe at some point I will make my listener use logsSubscribe, and getBlock as a fallback in case ws endpoint disconnect

Comment: Yeah, a combination approach will likely be your best option